# C++ How to set a string variable from a file?

Tags: c++, string, fstream

I want to know how can I read the WHOLE txt file and set it's content as 1 string in my program. I have declared my string:

```
const string SLOWA[ILOSC_WYRAZOW][ILOSC_POL] = 
{
    {"kalkulator", "Liczysz na tym."},
    {"monitor", "pokazuje obraz."},
    {"kupa", "robisz to w toalecie"}
};
```

Instead of having it in the program,  I want to have the inside of this string in a .txt file and read the whole content and set it to my string. Is it possible?

Comment: That's a 2D array of strings, not a string. Do you want to read 1 string from the file, or to fill this array?

Comment: I've never seen a string like yours

Comment: Yes it is. This is an 2D of strings. Search a bit.

Comment: I want to fill this array with what I have in my .txt file :)

Comment: Start with a tutorial or book on reading files using C++ streams.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
   ifstream file("d:\\data.txt");
   string content((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
   cout<<content;
   getchar();
   return 0;
}
```

here now `content` variable contains the whole data from your file.

file `data.txt` contains :

```
this is file handling
and this is contents.
```

output:

```
this is file handling
and this is contents.
```

Comment: What's the difference between your approach and `string content; file >> content;`

Comment: What does `string content((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>())` do. Load the whole file into string? Does it include whitespace?

Comment: @NeilKirk yes it includes whitespace.

Comment: It doesn't work with my file. I set string `SLOWA[ILOSC_WYRAZOW][ILOSC_POL] = { content };` Des not give me errors but when it's there... it doesn't compile. Runs OK but when I change something, it ignores it until i get rid of that string statement. LOL

Answer (score 0):

The below will work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    string line;
    string mystring;

    ifstream myfile ("example.txt");   // Need to be in the directory where this program resides.

    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while ( getline (myfile,line) )  // Get one line at a time.
        {
            mystring += line + '\n';    // '\n' at the end because streams read line by line
        }
        myfile.close();                   //Close the file
    }
    else
        cout << "Unable to open file";

    cout<<mystring<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

But have a look into streams how they work:

http://courses.cs.vt.edu/cs1044/Notes/C04.IO.pdf

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iolibrary/